# Delete is not working after add to cart click but works fine after refreshing page

Tags: jquery

I have a shopping cart page where if I click on add to cart then delete make page refresh and if after add to cart I reload page delete works well with out page refresh. I think there is any problem with jquery handler but I have try all the in place of "document ready" like window load and so on.

here is my code script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.delete').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      url: 'index.php',
      data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),
      beforeSend: function() {
        parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
      },
      success: function() {
        parent.slideUp(300,function() {
          parent.remove();
        });
      }
    });
  });

  $(".AddToCart").on('click',function() {
    var productId = this.id;
    var check_realtor = $(this).next('input').next('input').next('input').next('select.realtor').val();
    $('#labee_'+productId).val(check_realtor);
    var FormData = $('#productAddCart_'+productId).serialize();
    $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "functions.php?action=addToBasket",  
      data:FormData, 
      beforeSend:function(){$("#submit_indicator").show();},
      success: function(cartproduct) {
        //location.reload();
        $("#submit_indicator").hide();
        $(".shoping_cart").html(cartproduct);
      } 
    });
  })
});
```

here is the html markup for delete `<a href="?delete=',$cartdata->id,'" onclick="return:false" class="delete">Delete</a>`

and here is the markup for add to cart button `<button id="<?php echo $proDuctName->id;?>" type="button" class="btn btn-danger AddToCart">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> Add to Cart</button>`

Comment: Can you add your markup? A link to your page does other StackOverflowers no good once you fix it on your page. The answers here are not just to help you but to help others with similar problems. Please provide the markup for your page and we may be able to help.

Comment: @DutGRIFF i have added the element what i have used to call above mentioned jquery ajax script as all mark up has lots of php and inline css so it will make confusions. can you help me now?

Comment: If this answered your question you should accept it by clicking the check mark beside the answer that helped. If not please let me know what you need help with. I notice you have never accepted answers or upvoted on any of your questions. Please start doing your part so we know that these questions have been answered.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the page from submitting you are right by `e.preventDefault()` but you also want to include `return false;` at the end of that function. Try this

```
$('a.delete').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
      url: 'index.php',
      data: 'ajax=1&delete=' + parent.attr('id').replace('record-',''),
      beforeSend: function() {
      parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
    },
    success: function() {
      parent.slideUp(300,function() {
        parent.remove();
      });
    }
  });
  return false; //<<<< Add this line here
});
```

But you also don't want you link to submit to the new page. You are telling it to submit to `"?delete=',$cartdata->id,'"`. So change this to blank and add `onclick="return:false"` like this:

```
<a href="" onclick="return:false" class="delete">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for help But it made no effects page is still refreshing and just as i removed url from anchor so it doesn't delete record and after refresh it works. What i think the problem is created to add to cart ajax call as after that something is going wrong and my delete function didn't work

Comment: I am having trouble understanding that comment but this does work. I tried it out on your site. With your current revisions to the live site you removed `onclick="return:false"`. You should put this back like I have it. Once you have made all the edits above, if it still doesn't work let me know and I will look at your site. One note: On your live site you will need to edit the cart total. You should do this inside the success of the ajax call after `parent.remove()`.

Comment: @Omprks I can see this change worked for you. If it answered your question you should accept it. If you found it pretty helpful you should give it an upvote. I can tell by looking at your history you don't upvote or accept answers ever and that is pretty rude of you.